# https request takes over 10 seconds in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I am using the native `https` module. My code is below:

```
https.get("https://www.dwitter.net/api/dweets/?limit=1").on("response", function(response) {
    var body = "";
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

It takes up to a minute for the response to be recieved. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is nothing out of the ordinary here. Something else is probably causing the issue.

Comment: Probably not your fault. Did you try hitting that endpoint directly with your browser to see if that's the cause?

Comment: takes 400ms in a browser - takes 1400ms-1900ms in nodejs for me most of that being the delay until `response` is hit

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26302539/6647153. Also you should know that the browser use cache and that it set a lot of request headers (that you'll have to do it manually in nodejs) that speed the request like `user-agent` and `compression`.